# In Matlab's very old versions, what did "\" stand for in a conditional statement?

Tags: matlab, if-statement, conditional-statements, version

For my thesis work I was suggested to use a related code made in year 2000 on Matlab; when transcribing it I found the next syntax for some if loops:

```
if \ min(x)>= 0
   statement;
end
```

However it is not valid anymore for recent software's versions. I did some search on Google but using "\" is pretty ambiguous and found nothing out of conditionals. Do you know what does it stand for?

Comment: That syntax would have to be older than 2000. I started using it in 1996 and don't remember any use of "\" other than [matrix left division](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html). Are you sure it isn't just a typo that went undiscovered until now?

Comment: @gnovice Completely sure, they used the code to give basis to a thesis work from that year. Fortunately I work with the researcher who supervised it then, maybe it'll be better to ask him directly and then write down the answer here.

Comment: What are you using to view/edit the code? Was it put through any kind of conversions, like a translation from another language?

Comment: If it's pure MATLAB from 2000, as you say, get a copy of MATLAB from that year and run the code to see what it does. My money's on it being a syntax error

Comment: Have you tried asking on the Mathworks site?

Comment: Sorry for the late response: effectively, it was only a sintax mistake.